# How to create a VM guests network on ESXI 5

Tags: esxi

I have 4 windows VMs and a Mikrotik router vm as guest on an ESXI 5 host server. I want to set up a network so that i can assign private IPs on the windows VM and make the Mikrotik router VM their default gateway. I know how to create a virtual switch for the physical NICs on the ESXI host. How do I create a network of the VMs where the windows VMs will sit behind the Mikrotik router?

Answer (score 1):

In ESXi, create a virtual switch, not connected to the outside world and one that is connected to the outside world. On the MikroTik Router, give it 2 network connections, one to the internal and one to the external connections. All your Windows boxes should just connect to the internal. In the Mikrotik router, tell it to give IPs (DHCP server) to the internal boxes, and setup the external link however you need... Since the Windows boxes are not connected to the outside world, their only way out is though the Router.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old post, but still it might be useful for any one. How to create virtual switch and connect it with wan/lan.

http://aacable.wordpress.com/2012/12/10/vritualization-3-in-1-using-mikrotik-squid-proxy-radius-on-single-machine-to-save-resources/

Comment: Please consider expanding your answer with some excerpt from the linked article. See [How To Answer](http://superuser.com/questions/how-to-answer) for why it is important.